# Ruby TinyTds Hang on Result.each line

Tags: ruby, sql-server, tiny-tds

I have the following code:

```
def self.GetValuesFromDB(dataServer,database,sqlString)
    mprids = Array.new
    dbResult = Helper.CallDB(dataServer,database,sqlString)

    client = TinyTds::Client.new(:dataserver => dataServer, :database => database, :timeout => 900)

    dbResult = client.execute(sqlString)


    dbResults.each do |result| # hangs on this line for some SP calls
        mprids.push(result[0])
    end

    client.close
    return mprids
  end
```

it will sometimes hang on this line:

dbResults.each do |result| # hangs on this line for some SP calls

depending on which SP I call.  It's odd because the SP's I call all return the same datatype column so

Any ideas?